# How to split argument value passed to pl sql procedure

Tags: plsql, split, arguments, procedure

My requirement is, User will pass the value to one of my procedure input parameter and the format will be as shown below.

"XXX_Test,AL LDG,Test,Test,false,2,2"  "XXX_Feps,IN LDG,Test1,Test1,false,3,2" "XXX_GPP,IN LDG,Test2,Test2,false,3,4"  "XXX_FGP,IN LDG,Test3,Test3,false,4,4" and so on

It is single parameter value, here each string value is separated by space
[the above input value will be passed from CA Tool(scheduling tool) to input parameter of my pl sql procedure]

Inside the pl sql procedure, i need to process this value and need to find out how many arguments are passed(Strings separated by space) as well as need to split the attribute value into separate strings as follows

```
PARAM1 ="XXX_Test,AL LDG,Test,Test,false,2,2"  
PARAM2 ="XXX_Feps,IN LDG,Test1,Test1,false,3,2"  
PARAM3 ="XXX_GPP,IN LDG,Test2,Test2,false,3,4"  
PARAM4 ="XXX_FGP,IN LDG,Test3,Test3,false,4,4"
```

and in this case the count will be 4(since 4 strings are passed)

How can we achieve this requirement in pl sql programming? Can some one help me on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A query like this one would do the trick:

```
WITH params AS (
   SELECT '"XXX_Test,AL LDG,Test,Test,false,2,2" "XXX_Feps,IN  LDG,Test1,Test1,false,3,2" "XXX_GPP,IN LDG,Test2,Test2,false,3,4" "XXX_FGP,IN LDG,Test3,Test3,false,4,4"' param FROM DUAL
)
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(param,'(".+?")',1,LEVEL)
FROM params
CONNECT BY  LENGTH(SUBSTR(param,DECODE(REGEXP_INSTR(param,'(".+?")',1,LEVEL),0,NULL,REGEXP_INSTR(param,'(".+?")',1,LEVEL)))) <= LENGTH(SUBSTR(param,DECODE(REGEXP_INSTR(param,'(".+?")',1,LEVEL),0,NULL,REGEXP_INSTR(param,'(".+?")',1,LEVEL))))
```

The idea is to extract each occurrence of the parameter for each level of the hierarchichal query

Comment: This breaks if there is a null param passed ("").  In case that could happen.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('"XXX_Test,AL LDG,Test,Test,false,2,2" "XXX_Feps,IN LDG,Test1,Test1,false,3,2" "XXX_GPP,IN LDG,Test2,Test2,false,3,4" "XXX_FGP,IN LDG,Test3,Test3,false,4,4"','[^ "" ]+', 1, level) 
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR('"XXX_Test,AL LDG,Test,Test,false,2,2" "XXX_Feps,IN LDG,Test1,Test1,false,3,2" "XXX_GPP,IN LDG,Test2,Test2,false,3,4" "XXX_FGP,IN LDG,Test3,Test3,false,4,4" ', '[^ "" ]+', 1, level) is not null;
```

Comment: Perhaps the editing broke this?  Does not return the desired results as it is right now.  It fails on the embedded space.

Answer (score 0):

Does a count, allowing for a possible null param.  Don't know if that's a concern or not:

```
WITH params AS (
   SELECT '"XXX_Test,AL LDG,Test,Test,false,2,2" "" "XXX_GPP,IN LDG,Test2,Test2,false,3,4" "XXX_FGP,IN LDG,Test3,Test3,false,4,4"' param FROM DUAL
)
SELECT REGEXP_COUNT(param, '".*?"')
FROM params;
```

Applied to splitting the values, while stripping the double-quotes and preserving NULL params (assumption is you'll go on to process the comma-delimited list then):

```
WITH params AS (
   SELECT '"XXX_Test,AL LDG,Test,Test,false,2,2" "" "XXX_GPP,IN LDG,Test2,Test2,false,3,4" "XXX_FGP,IN LDG,Test3,Test3,false,4,4"' param FROM DUAL
)
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(param, '"(.*?)"', 1, LEVEL, NULL, 1)
FROM params
CONNECT BY  LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(param, '".*?"');
```

EDIT: I see from another question you posted that you need to preserve the double-quotes.  in that case the matching pattern should be '(".*?")'

Then, after you have your param list, if you want to parse that (allows for NULLS too); This gets the 5th item for example:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('XXX_Test,,Test,Test,false,2,2', '([^,]*)(,|$)', 1, 5, NULL, 1)  from dual;
```

Comment: Made an edit to show how you can preserve the double-quotes by including them in the group.